# How do I display a gif in my React Native app?

Tags: android, react-native

I have created an app with `react-native init AwesomeProject`.

I can't display a gif despite following the instructions in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html. When I comment out `compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.8.1'` my app runs properly.

My build.gradle dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.8.1' // For animated GIF support
}
```

I'm using Windows 10 and an Android emulator targetting 8.1. When I run `react-native run-android` I get an error "AwesomeProject has stopped".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: I'm using VSCode so I don't have access to Android Studio.

Comment: My app crashes instantly. I can't use Chrome remote debugging for that.

Comment: Crashes are reported to logcat. Android studio provides a way to read the logcat, but there are other ways to do that. Try reading the stack trace with `adb logcat`.

Comment: Did you figure out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this for showing .gif

It is best in it.

https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-react-native